# How to add headers to a Sencha Touch proxy class after it has been instantiated

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I currently have a custom proxy class like so:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.proxy.SecureProxy', {
    alias: 'proxy.securerestproxy',
    extend: 'Ext.data.proxy.Rest',  

    constructor: function () {
        this.headers = {
           // "AUTH-TOKEN": MyApp.app.authToken
        }
        this.callParent(arguments);
    },

    config: {
        headers: {
            //"AUTH-TOKEN": MyApp.app.authToken
        }
    }       
});
```

The problem is,  I can't set in config or in constructor my header value as this is too early in the process. This class is instantiated before MyApp.app.authToken is set, before Authentication has taken place.  Is there any way that I can set the header value to the auth token in the app class, either after authentication has taken place or is it possible to do this in a pre-request event of the rest proxy?

The problem is in the API docs, there is only 1 event: Exception.  I thought there might be a BeforeRequest event on the proxy that I could use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At any time you can do

```
var headers = proxy.getHeaders() || {};
headers["AUTH-TOKEN"] = MyApp.app.authToken;
proxy.setHeaders(headers)
```

EDIT: it is also possible to change Ext.Ajax singleton:

```
var defaultHeaders = Ext.Ajax.getDefaultHeaders() || {};

if (!defaultHeaders["AUTH-TOKEN"]) {
    defaultHeaders["AUTH-TOKEN"]  = MyApp.app.authToken;
    Ext.Ajax.setDefaultHeaders(defaultHeaders)
}
```

Comment: Not sure I understand the example. Whereabouts in the app can I get a reference to 'proxy'? I never instantiate it directly, only indirectly via the link between the the store & proxy.

Comment: You can use the getProxy() method on a Model or store to get a reference to the proxy.

Comment: Great, your code works! The setDefaultHeaders in combination with the getDefaultHeaders call did the trick. Thanks.